# QML Item cliping shadow ShaderEffect

Tags: qt, qml, shader

I'm trying to add shadow to my component using the ShaderEffect, and the problem is that the parent item clips the shader effect. Previously I used Qt Graphical Effects, but now I am using QT6, where this component is removed.

Currently I'm using shaders from ShaderEffects example.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: parent.height * 0.6
        width:  parent.width * 0.9
        Rectangle{
            id: mrect
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: height * 0.2
            color: "yellow"
            visible: !shadow.visible
        }

        ShaderEffectSource{
            id: theSource
            sourceItem: mrect
        }

        ShaderEffect {
            id: shadow
            width: mrect.width
            height: mrect.height
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            property variant source: theSource
            property variant shadow: ShaderEffectSource {
                sourceItem: ShaderEffect {
                    width: mrect.width
                    height: mrect.height
                    property variant delta: Qt.size(0.0, 1.0 / height)
                    property variant source: ShaderEffectSource {
                        sourceItem: ShaderEffect {
                            width: mrect.width * 1.5
                            height: mrect.height * 1.5
                            property variant delta: Qt.size(1.0 / width, 0.0)
                            property variant source: theSource
                            fragmentShader: "shaders/blur.frag.qsb"
                        }
                    }
                    fragmentShader: "shaders/blur.frag.qsb"
                }
            }
            property real angle: 0.5
            property variant delta: Qt.size(15 / width, 15 / height)
            property real darkness: 0.2
            fragmentShader: "shaders/shadow.frag.qsb"
        }
    }
}
```

I read Qt documentation for this types but couldn't find any helpful information to solve my problem. But this doesn't make sense to me because shaders would be useless for dropping shadows in this case.

Comment: You could use https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html with Qt 6.4. The version 6.5 will rbing back the graphical effects under the name MultiEffect https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-effects-multieffect.html

Comment: @iam_peter Thanks for your answer. If I can't find any solution, I'll wait for Qt 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the `sourceItem` of the `ShaderEffectSource` a padding depending on how big the offset of your shadow will get. The issue is that the `sourceItem` is used to pick the color from and also draw on top of it.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: shaderEffectSource
        sourceItem: item
    }

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 40

        Item {
            id: item
            width: 300
            height: 300

            Rectangle {
                width: 200
                height: 200
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: "salmon"
            }
        }

        ShaderEffect {
            width: 300
            height: 300
            property variant source: shaderEffectSource
            property variant shadow: ShaderEffectSource {
                sourceItem: ShaderEffect {
                    width: item.width
                    height: item.height
                    property variant delta: Qt.size(0.0, 1.0 / height)
                    property variant source: ShaderEffectSource {
                        sourceItem: ShaderEffect {
                            width: item.width
                            height: item.height
                            property variant delta: Qt.size(1.0 / width, 0.0)
                            property variant source: shaderEffectSource
                            fragmentShader: "shaders/blur.frag.qsb"
                        }
                    }
                    fragmentShader: "shaders/blur.frag.qsb"
                }
            }
            property real angle: 0.5
            property variant offset: Qt.point(15.0 * Math.cos(angle), 15.0 * Math.sin(angle))
            property variant delta: Qt.size(offset.x / width, offset.y / height)
            property real darkness: 0.2
            fragmentShader: "shaders/shadow.frag.qsb"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]